# Adding Action Bar

Tags: android, android-actionbar

I'm trying to add the Action Bar of on but it isn't shown...

I'm following this [document](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/actionbar.html) and as I can see, the action bar should be included within the activities of the app (if it's running on Android 3.0 AVD, which is my case).

Here are some parts of my code:

**AndroidManifest.xml**

```
//...
<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="8"
    android:targetSdkVersion="15" />

<application
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Holo"  >
//...
```

**MenuActivity.java**

```
public class MenuActivity extends Activity {

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_menu);

    //...
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.activity_menu, menu);
    return true;
}
}
```

**/res/menu/activity_menu.xml**

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:id="@+id/menu_settings"
        android:title="@string/menu_settings"
        android:orderInCategory="100"
        android:showAsAction="ifRoom" />
</menu>
```

What am I missing here?

Answer (score 2):

[ActionBars](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/actionbar.html) require Android API level 11 or greater (Android 3.0.0 or greater).

```
<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="11"
    android:targetSdkVersion="15" />
```

Alternatively, install and use the [Android Support Library](http://developer.android.com/tools/extras/support-library.html).

Comment: I tried that but it's the same. As I understood, it should work the way that I have: when running on a device older than 3.0, the action bar isn't included and when the version is later than 3.0 the action bar should be shown...

Answer (score 0):

in place of `android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Holo"`
try `android:theme="@style/AppTheme"` in `AndroidManifest.xml` file